# Sqlite order BY with multiple attribute

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Does it make any difference if I just use either of following

`select * from TABLE order BY CLM1` OR

`select * from TABLE order BY CLM1, CLM2`

In my observation it always considering first column for order BY clause.

Or am I missing any concept here ?

UPDATE: How this is not making any difference in my case, might be I'm still missing an key point. Please suggest that.

Even this have ***id & age*** column which have few similar values but not difference.

[image]

Comment: @CL & Varro you both speaking same and that might be true. Please check my updated answer I have update my observation.

Comment: Well, sure - as both my and CL's comments indicate, the *first* sorting will be by "id".  Since the id field is unique, there is no need to do a secondary sort on the "age" column.

Comment: so in case if first column hold unique value & so added second column will not make any difference, is this you saying ? Though I'll check with non-unique column value as well.

Comment: Yes,  if the first column is *constrained* to hold unique values, then there is no point in specifying a secondary column for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The second example will sort by CLM1 *first* and *then* by CLM2, so yes, it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The second ORDER BY column makes a difference only if there are rows with the same value in the first column.